# Linker error of unused variable and function

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker-errors, cl

I have written following test program

```
int proc1();
extern int globalvar;

int func1 ()
{
    return globalvar + 1;
}

int func2()
{
    return proc1()+3;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see that this program is not doing anything. However, while compiling it, I faced linker error of `globalvar` and `int proc1()` despite the facts that these are not going to be referenced from the entry point function `main`.
I faced problem on both Windows(using `cl`) and Linux(using `gcc`).

Is there any way to instruct the compiler/linker not to link this unreferenced global variable and function from the entry point (on cl, gcc and clang)?

Exact error message on Windows:

```
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int globalvar" (?globalvar@@3HA) referenced in function "int __cdecl func1(void)" (?func1@@YAHXZ)
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl proc1(void)" (?proc1@@YAHXZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl func2(void)" (?func2@@YAHXZ)
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Comment: `these are not going to be used in the program` - then what do you think `return globalvar + 1;` and `return proc1() + 3;` do?

Comment: @user3477950: See the edit. These are not goint to be referenced from the entry point function main.

Comment: and then what? their callers are not `static`, so **even** if the linker does LTO, it cannot possibly eliminate them...

Comment: @user3477950: Is this because these function can be used in other translation unit? But I have only one translation unit.

Comment: @dbasic i think you got undefined reffernce error. where you defined `proc1()` function. and `globalvar` variable.

Comment: @Jayesh: Yes. See the exact error message.

Comment: @user3477950 I'm pretty sure LTO *can* remove these functions. The whole point is that LTO can work with knowledge, not safe assumptions. GCC's `-fwhole-program` can do the same.

Comment: Seems very risky to me. Why not implement some abstraction layer between your code and the backend? This would solve your problems without unnecessary compiler "magic"...

Comment: @ams I don't think so. What if another program wants to link against the resulting executable?

Comment: @user3477950 then they're breaking the rules of LTO. The whole point of LTO is that it can *know* what's used where, and by what.

Comment: @ams consequently, if the rules of LTO are broken, then LTO can't be used.

Comment: @user3477950, "if the rules of LTO are broken, then LTO *mustn't* be used." There, fixed that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this, in `gcc`, like this:

```
gcc -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections test.c
```

That does two things:

1. It instructs the compiler to emit each function in its own 'section' in the binary file.
2. It instructs the linker to discard (garbage collect) sections that are not referenced.

This means that `func1` and `func2` will be discarded, and therefore there will be not more references to `globalvar` or `proc1`.

Comment: No idea, you're the one who's actually used those tools. ;-)